# Html Javascript that calculates fee based on a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I am a noob but I love creating websites and tools. I was unable to find how to calculate fee based on a range of numbers online so I think I'm just going to ask someone here.

Example:
Total Amount [100], Fee [5]

| Amount | Fee |
| --- | --- |
| 1-100 | 5 |
| 101 - 199 | 7 |
| 200 - 299 | 8 |

So if user inputs 100 as the total amount. It will show 5 as fee. If user inputs 201 then the fee will be 8. I hope you get it. It's hard for me to explain too. Thanks so much.

Nothing yet. Currently, I can only modify codes a little. I haven't studied them yet from the ground up. I only self study and I'm kinda busy so I don't have much time learning too much.

Comment: [Useful documentation from MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals).

Comment: Can we expect that no amount is skipped? E.g. an entry for `1-10` then for `15-20`, but no entry for `11-14` would never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javascript` with conditions like this:

```js
function calculateFee(e) {
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var fee = 0;
  if(number >= 1 && number <= 100) {
    fee = 5;
  } else if(number >= 101 && number <= 199) {
    fee = 7;
  } else if(number >= 200 && number <= 299) {
    fee = 8;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("fee").textContent = fee;
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="number" min="1" id="number">
<button onclick="calculateFee()">Calculate fee</button>

<p>
  Fee : <span id="fee">0</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This works perfectly like the other one below. I just needed to tweak it to my liking.

Answer (score 1):

By keeping your pricing structure in an array (ascending order for the `amount`) you can then use a simple `Array.find()` to find the right fee. In this way
you can easily update your pricing structure without having to change the rest of your JavaScript code.

```js
const fees=[[100,5],[200,7],[300,8]];

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 let n=+ev.target.value; // the unary + operator forces the value to become a number
 console.log(`amount:${n}, fee:${fees.find(([k,v])=>k>=n)?.[1]??"unknown!"}`)
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

The optional chaining operator `.?[1]` allows you to access the element with index `[1]` if it exists and returns `undefined` if it does not. In the latter case the `??` operator steps in and returns the immediately following string `"unknown!"` as the result.

Another feature worth explaining might be the function definition in my `fees.find()` method, `([k,v])=>k>=n`. This is a function in "fat arrow" notation, introduced in ES5, with

- a "destructuring" argument `([k,v])`: This expression picks out the first two elements of a given array-type argument and assigns them to the two function-local variables `k` and `v`
- and a function body `k>=n`, a comparison, resulting in `true` or `false`. As is typical for one-line fat arrow functions (those without enclosing curly brackets `{}`) the result of the one-line expression is returned *implicitly* (without the need for a `return` statement).

Comment: While this is a nice and short solution, the OP mentioned they are unfamiliar with coding. Your solution contains some language features that may seem intimidating for beginners, e.g. type coercion (unary plus), destructuring, etc. Optional chaining and nullish coalescence are also more advanced topics, but you explained them nicely.

Comment: Never treat a noob like a moron. I always like to encourage newcomers to look at old and new language features alike. And, when there is a way to avoid redundancy, I tend to go for it - even if I might have to think a little longer and work a little harder at first. Usually it pays off in the end!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function feeCalculator(amount) {
 var fees = 0;
 if (amount >= 1 && amount <= 100) {
  fees = 5;
 } else if (amount >= 101 && amount <= 199) {
  fees = 7;
 } else if (amount >= 200 && amount <= 299) {
  fees = 8
 }
 document.getElementById("fee").innerHTML = fees;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <label for="number">Number:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="number" onchange="feeCalculator(this.value)"><br><br>
    <label for="fee">Fees:</label>
    <h4 id="fee"></h4>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I just needed to tweak it to my liking.